# web application c#

Tags: c#, client

Im trying to make a a cleint/server web application where eventually the client application will be deploy on the internet.  People told me to use visual studio WCF duplex but im confuse on how that works.  I know for a simple server/client application using sockets, u can just use console for the server and then a windows form for the client.

So how does WCF duplex work, will it be used for both the server and the client side or do i sill use console for the server??  Also how do they establish a connection, in sockets you use ip address and a port.. HELP!

Answer (score 0):

There are many WCF bindings that enable full-duplex communication. WCF servers and clients are able to use sockets among other means of communication. With WCF you can still use the IP Address:Port address system to expose and consume services.

With WCF you still can use Console Apps, Windows Forms or Web Applications to expose or consume those services. It brings no restriction at this point.

WCF will provide flexibility, since once you want to change the binding or the address, you can do it in the configuration file, instead of doing it by changing the code.